# JBoss 7.1.1 Http Connection Timeout

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I am trying to set http connection timeout for JBoss 7.1.1 but I just can't find inside standalone.xml where to change this setting. Does anyone have an idea where I can change the default setting of 60 sec?

Answer (score 3):

You can configure a connection timeout of the HTTP connector by system property:

```
org.apache.coyote.http11.DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT
```

It can be added to your standalone.conf file:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=60000"
```

But according to this:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-4566

It may be available only from JBoss 7.1.2

Comment: Tried in Wildfly 10, didn't work. Still getting Socket timeout exception.