# Socket timeout in jboss as 7.1.1

Tags: jboss

Hello Developers and experts.

We have as application deployed over `jboss-as-7.1.1`. We also have a webservice deployed on same. There is a socket timeout configured as 60 sec somewhere internally which if breached, when application calls for answer from web-service, causes this issue:

> error:SocletTimeoutException:read timed out.

Please help me to increase this value to higher value say 180 sec if it is some config file or some change in internal libraries. Can this issue will be fixed by upgrading the `jboss-as7.1.1`

Comment: Maybe [thats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085971/jboss-7-1-1-http-connection-timeout) what you are looking for?

Comment: Is this issue fixed in higher version of jboss like wildfly?